# How to convert "ASCII" to "hex" in python

Tags: python

How to convert "ASCII" to "HEX" in python

I have one file need to read . but use below code it only can show ASCII

```
with open('Hello.DAT','rb') as f:
    data= f.read()  
    print(data)
```

It can print data in this format:

> 01201602180000020000000007000000000054000000000000\x0

How do I to convert this data to HEX values, like  this:

> 30 31 32 30 31 36 30 32 31 38 30 30 30 30 30 32 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
>   30 30 37 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 35 34 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
>   30 30 30 30 5c 78 30

Answer (score 9):

Assuming python3:

```
with open('Hello.DAT','rb') as f:
    data = f.read()  
    print(" ".join("{:02x}".format(c) for c in data))
```

(in python2 change `format(c)` to `format(ord(c))`)

Comment: thx a lot for your answer, but use your code ' it show **TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found**

Answer (score 1):

You can just encode to hex:

```
In [6]: with open("test.txt") as f:
         print(" ".join([ch.encode("hex")  for line in f for ch in line]))
...:     
30 31 32 30 31 36 30 32 31 38 30 30 30 30 30 32 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 37 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 35 34 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 5c 78 30 0a
```

Or for python3 just call hex:

```
In [18]: with open("test.txt", "rb") as f:            
            print(" ".join([hex(ch)[2:]  for line in f for ch in line]))  
 ....:     
30 31 32 30 31 36 30 32 31 38 30 30 30 30 30 32 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 37 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 35 34 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 5c 78 30 a
```

Comment: it can work，thx a lot . can you tell why hex() need to add [2:]. what is [2:] ?

Comment: @square, just to remove the  `0x` prefix, you can use `"{:x}".format(ch) ` if you prefer and it will give you the same output